# React Server-Side Rendering Memory Leak

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-server

The code below according to the link [react](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#adding-event-listeners-or-subscriptions) says that:

> Unfortunately, this can cause memory leaks for server rendering (where
>   componentWillUnmount will never be called)

```
// Before
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      subscribedValue: this.props.dataSource.value,
    });

    // This is not safe; it can leak!
    this.props.dataSource.subscribe(
      this.handleSubscriptionChange
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.dataSource.unsubscribe(
      this.handleSubscriptionChange
    );
  }

  handleSubscriptionChange = dataSource => {
    this.setState({
      subscribedValue: dataSource.value,
    });
  };
}
```

I cant understand how this can be a memory leak in server-side. For example, lets say we have this code which is rendered server-side and the ExampleComponent contains the memory leak.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './components/index'

const serverRender =  () =>{
    return ReactDomServer.renderToString(<ExampleComponent />);
};

export default serverRender;
```

When this returns to the client, the rendered components are not attached to anywhere and are ready to be GB collected. So why is there a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.props.dataSource` is something external and can live longer than the component calling `subscribe`. `handleSubscriptionChange` will be referenced by `this.props.dataSource`. Also the component itself might be referenced by `this` inside `handleSubscriptionChange`. So GB won't clean up `ExampleComponent` at all.

Since [componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) is deprecated you probably should not worry about these details and just use `componentDidMaount`.

Comment: The this.props.dataSource will live longer as long as Server will keep running right?

Comment: It is not clear from the example and it might be a global variable on the server. It depends on the server code and `props` passed to `ExampleComponent`.

Comment: It's a best practice to do all server side calls in `componentDidMount`. Yes till the call returns from server `this.props.dataSource` will live.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is hinted on in the docs:

> People often assume that `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` are always paired, but that is not guaranteed

There's the obvious reason is that `componentWillMount` runs when component is **about to** mount so if mounting is interrupted then the component will never  have mounted and therefore will never unmount. However there's also the hinted reason in the previous section in the docs which shows the code:

```
componentWillMount() {

    this.setState({
      subscribedValue: this.props.dataSource.value,
    });

    // This is not safe; it can leak!
    this.props.dataSource.subscribe(
      this.handleSubscriptionChange
    );

}
```

and says

> The above code is problematic for both server rendering (where the external data won’t be used) and the upcoming async rendering mode (where the request might be initiated multiple times).

From this one can assume that `componentWillMount` does run during SSR and also runs when hydrating on the client-side meaning there's an additional unnecessary request being made causing a potential memory leak on the server.

However if you use `componentDidMount` then this is guaranteed to:

1. Run only on the client side
2. Ensure that `componentWillUnmount` will always run afterwards